# How do I find all distinct values for each record (identified by ID) in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

### Data

This is an import from another place, so my data in BigQuery looks something like this:

```
order_id | owner_pk | owner_sk | other_properties | currency
```

### Notes

- PK+SK are the index in the original dataset (but not here in BQ)
- Order ID is unique for PK+SK in the original dataset
- Together, OrderID+PK+SK are unique for each record (as per the original dataset)

### Problem

I'd like to find if there are orders (order_id) coming from the same owner (PK+SK) that have different (distinct?) `currency` values. I don't need the actual orders, true/false is ok.

- option 1: all orders coming from the same owner have the same currency
- option 2: there is an order with a different currency within one owner

Any help with querying for that is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  I would return the currencies as well as the number:

```
select owner_pk, owner_sk,
       array_agg(distinct currency) as currencies,
       count(distinct currency) as num_currencies
from t
group by owner_pk, owner_sk;
```